# Why in archive page doesn´t show read more button with excerpt?

Tags: filters, excerpt

in this page 
https://blog.despierta.org/page/3/

Last post is with excerpt.

If my posts don´t have excerpt show read more If I add excerpt the button doesn´t show.

In `functions.php`

```
    // Replaces the excerpt "Read More" text by a link
function clean_blogging_excerpt_more($more) {
    if ( is_admin() ) {
        return $more;
    }

    global $post;
    return '<p><a class="readmore" href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '">Leer Más</a></p>';
}
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'clean_blogging_excerpt_more');
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong filter. Depending on how your theme is built, there may be two solutions.

1. If the theme uses the [`wp_trim_excerpt`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_trim_excerpt/) function, the 
   `excerpt_more` filter inside that function will only be called if
   there is no excerpt passed to that function. At the end of that
   function there still is the `wp_trim_excerpt` filter that you could
   use to append anything to the result.
2. If the theme uses the [`get_the_excerpt`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_excerpt/) function to echo
   the excerpt there is a filter with the same name that you may use.

Both solutions may work at the same time, so don't overdo it.

Comment: thank you for you answer. If I use get_the_excerpt the buttom show in all pages but the excerpt disappears

Comment: Yes, because that filter works a bit differently. It gets the excerpt as a parameter and you must return it with the more-link concatenated. You can see the precise call if you follow the link.